# Where are some good sites I can find for free action RPGs?

Tags: online-roleplaying

I really like to role-play online with people, but I only have a few people I know who role-play, and I wanted to know if there were any forum sites that are solely for role-playing and having fun.

Answer (score 0):

[Http://roll20.net](http://roll20.net)

A large group of individuals play on a constant map known as corymyr with pathfinder rules to build some hrs. Or you can hunt for games setup at times shown. Some games are strict on consitancy though so make sure your scheduele will work with thiers. 
All rpgs are present on site. Still depends on whom is playing what though.